# Group by substring in ponyorm

Tags: python, mysql, ponyorm

```
select substr(word,1,1) as alpha, count(*) as count
from words
group by substr(word,1,1);
```

I want to implement this in PonyORM, can anyone help me to write the query statement? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's quite easy

```
query = select(
    (w.word[0], count())
    for w in Words
)
```

Answered by kozlovsky on [github](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/348)

As to using this **query** object:

```
char_count_pair = list(query) 
for start_char, c in char_count_pair:
    print('char:', start_char, ', count:', c)
```